# django how do i access a modelforms variables?

Tags: python, django

i have a modelform like so:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    storyId = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    postId = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

so now i want to change the value of the "storyId"

i've found that, in my code i need to do this:

```
form = CommentForm()
form.initial['storyId'] = xyz
```

or in the **init** of the model i need this:

```
self.initial['storyId'] = xyz
```

what is the "initial" doing? Why cannot i just go straight to:

```
form = CommentForm()
form.storyId = xyz
```

thanks!

UPDATE if i run `form.storyId = xyz`, then in the template, I will not see the value passed in. If i run

```
form.initial['storyId'] = xyz
```

then in the template i *do* see the values passed in! No other code changes, any ideas?

Comment: You also can pass `initial` as parameter when you create your form `form = CommentForm(initial={'storyId':xyz})`

Comment: thankyou, i did not know that and am grateful to find it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter "initial" is used in forms.Form class generally to initialize a value that you would like to see as auto-filled, when the form is rendered.

In case of ModelForm, initial is used when you need to autofill a field that's called from the forms's **init** method.

```
form = CommentForm()
form.storyId = xyz
```

In the above code you are  assigning directly the value to a property of a Python Instance, then the type of the property also changes.

The variable storyId is actually a django.forms.fields.IntegerField, and this has a parameter "initial" that would initialize the value.

Once you assign form.storyId=xyz, then storyId, takes the value of xyz, and will not be rendered as a form field.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Modelform is just a class so,you can access modelform variables straight away. There's no need for initial.